# Не сохраняется фото в PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer, qpixmap

Изображение должно загрузиться и по нажатию на кнопку "*Сохранить фото*"  - сохраниться в папке по относительному пути `self.pixmap.save("/images/")`.

Как правильно выполнить сохранение файла?

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(198, 236)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 91, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 0, 91, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 181, 161))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 198, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузить фото"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сохранить фото"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.upload_image)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.adding)

    def upload_image(self):
        self.imagePath, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Select Image", "",
                                                        "Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp)")
        print(self.imagePath)
        self.pixmap = QPixmap(self.imagePath)
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap.scaled(301, 281))

    def adding(self):
        self.pixmap.save("/images/")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> bool QPixmap::save(const QString &fileName, const char *format = nullptr, int quality = -1) const
>
> Сохраняет растровое изображение в файл с заданным именем файла, используя указанный формат файла изображения и коэффициент качества. Возвращает true в случае успеха; в противном случае возвращает false.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(198, 236)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 91, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 0, 91, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 181, 161))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 198, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузить фото"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сохранить фото"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.upload_image)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.adding)

    def upload_image(self):
        self.imagePath, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Select Image", "",
                                                        "Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp)")
        print(self.imagePath)
        self.pixmap = QPixmap(self.imagePath)
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap.scaled(301, 281))

    def adding(self):
#        self.pixmap.save("/images/")
        if self.imagePath:
            _path = self.imagePath.split('/')[-1]
            print(_path)
            self.pixmap.save("images/{}".format(_path))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```